# Write a function that takes a list of values and returns a dictionary

Tags: javascript

Write a function that takes a list of values and returns a dictionary in the format below

```
Sample Input:
[“book”, 3, “pin”, 3.5]
Sample Output
{
string :[“book”, “pin”],
number:[3,5]
} */
```

Above is the code challenge question and i dont really know where to start
I understand dictionary key/value js fucnction.. i have tried the following

```
var dict = []; // create an empty array

dict.push({
    String:   ["book" , "pin"] , number: [3 , 4]
});
// repeat this last part as needed to add more key/value pairs
console.log(dict)..
```

it displays the output i need but im not sure my process is correct

Comment: did you try to write code on your own? Please upload your code and mention where you are getting the problem. We can help you then. SO is not the code writing service.

Comment: The result is supposed to be an object, not an array. And your "process" handles the exact example case only, it can't handle arbitrary input.

Comment: @RaghavGarg The attempt is in the question!?

Comment: @Yoshi, I believe it's not the attempt, he just hard coded the values to indicate that he wanted to replace this step with the actual code which will do the actual work. Also, OP said in comments `repeat this last part as needed to add more key/value pairs`. So I think he didn't really try to write the code.

Comment: Maybe, though until confirmation, it could also just be so that this actually is all the OP can do at the moment. It might not be much, but we all started at some point.

Comment: So how did 3.5 became 5 ?

Comment: @RaghavGarg, im new to javascript.and also new to stackoverflow. barely 2 weeks old in js and oojs.. Im just trying to test my self with a few js code challenges. I understand how to create a dict with key/value pairs. I just need help in developing the right solution for the challenge. I understand this is not a code writing service.. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
var list = ["book", 3, "pin", 4];

function toObject(arr){

    var dict = {
        string: [],
        number: []
    };

    for( var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++ ){

        if( typeof arr[i] === "string"){
            dict.string.push(arr[i]);
        } else {
            dict.number.push(arr[i]);
        }

    }

    return dict;

}

toObject(list);
```

Comment: @kellboy22 You replied to my answer instead of the comments on your question. I wrote the code for you anyway now. So is this what you needed?

Comment: sorry my bad at @Tyrone. im new here. yes i needed something of that nature. The input format is perfect but what about the output?.. does it display as the format in the sample output of the question? how do i print the output statement to console.. It tells me dict not defined when i use console.log

Comment: Well, first of all I recommend you start learning javascript from scratch to understand the basics. And second you can paste this code to your chrome dev console that you open with CTRL + Shift + J and see the result, it returns an object with two arrays inside for both strings and numbers. If you need any further help, after researching and learning the basics I'll help.

Comment: I appreciate this Tyrone. I already learnt basics at codecademy but they didnt cover much. i still understand a bunch.. Thanks a lot. But i have one more challenge to hit you. I'm hoping you could assist. Most lads here aren't very friendly

Comment: hello @PredatorWD the output seems wrong. its returns `{string: Array(2), number: Array(2)}` . can review and get back to me? thanks

Comment: @kellboy22 Isn't that exactly what you wrote as a sample output in your question? When you click on the drop down arrow at the beginning of the object you get in the console you see both numbers and strings as arrays and their values.